# "Due to expectedly inclement weather conditions..."

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, adjectives

Does this sound okay?

> "Due to expectedly inclement weather conditions..."

I am especially interested in the use of "expectedly."

Comment: The word _conditions_ is superfluous, which makes the sentence verbose: "Due to **inclement weather, the** picnic has been canceled" is sufficient, clear, and complete.

Answer (score 3):

It's really just a matter of context (i.e. - the intended meaning).

If the weather condition being spoken is in the future, but the forecast says it will be [inclement](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inclement) when it does arrive (so you're cancelling the village fete, or whatever), then of course it's *expected*.

But if the predicted weather *has* already started, it's perfectly grammatical to say it's *expectedly inclement*, if in fact that's what it is (in line with prior expectations). OED defines...

> **expectedly** adv. *in the manner expected, according to expectation;*

Note that as J.R. says, *expectedly* is [very rare](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expectedly,unexpectedly&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) compared to *unexpectedly*. We usually use ***as*** expected when that's the syntactic functionality we want (effectively, *He appeared as expected* is adverbial usage).

But if we reverse the expectations (and use simpler meteorological terminology), I have no problem with...

> 1: Due to unexpected bad weather the fete has been cancelled
>    2: Due to unexpectedly bad weather the fete has been cancelled

It should be fairly obvious that in #1 we weren't expecting bad weather at all (maybe the forecast said it would be sunny). Whereas in #2 we knew the weather would be bad (but we probably hadn't expected it to be *so* bad we'd have to cancel the fete). Unexpectedly, it was even worse than we had anticipated.

---

I must admit I don't know why we prefer *as expected* over *expectedly* in nearly all cases. It may be connected to the fact that we have many alternatives *(naturally, obviously, predictably, typically, clearly, foreseeably, logically, etc.* plus phrases like *it goes without saying)*.

Such words are often used in sensitive/loaded contexts, so it's likely people learn to be extra careful with them. Perhaps *expectedly* is avoided because it raises the question of *expected by **whom**?* in too many contexts where we'd rather be more circumspect. So we tend to opt for more "impersonal" alternatives.

Comment: @Julie: As you'll discover if you stick around here on ELL, that text above is an **Answer** (*this* text is a **Comment**! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers OP did thank you for what it was: more of a comment than an answer. :)

Comment: @Kris: I don't wish to seem humourless, but I don't follow that. Granted, I added what's effectively a comment/suggestion about why we might prefer *as expected* over *expectedly*. But I'd already answered OP's actual question - it's an uncommon (but perfectly valid) construction, with an expectedly different meaning to the one we'd normally see.

Answer (score 1):

*Expectedly inclement* is an odd word pairing. When I did a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22expectedly%20inclement%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) on it, I found 8 hits – all [but one](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%22expectedly%20inclement%22&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&ved=0CGEQFjAH&url=http://toromagazine.com/lifestyle/test-drive/e3bfae6b-221a-b494-b127-d8877f61f08e/The-Loch-Ness-Monster/&ei=Njd6UdCjOqmY2wX-zYH4Cg&usg=AFQjCNGjUJkhXdl7GnaRD6VdS8Y7KN0KYA&sig2=L8pD0zfzHeXprX_je1hdcA&bvm=bv.45645796,d.b2I) of them was tied to a user named Julie on the Stack Exchange network. Here's the one that wasn't:

> My time behind the wheel didn’t provide the opportunity to verify
>   these figures — the expectedly inclement Scottish weather and
>   slow-moving traffic proved insurmountable — but it did provide ample
>   evidence that the car has significant reserves of power.

My first thought was that *expected weather* seems more natural than *expectedly weather*, and the inclusion of word *inclement* does not affect that.

> Due to expected inclement weather conditions, we are canceling tomorrow's picnic.

If you use the adjective *expected* – instead of the adverb *expectedly* – then it sounds just fine.

However, as others mentioned, there are some cases where your clause could work. It's a bit tricky, though, because *expected* (or *expectedly*) *inclement weather* could refer to weather conditions in the present, past, or future, and which one you're referring to might affect whether or not *expectedly inclement* is the right way to describe it.

Also, it's worth noting that the word *expectedly* is much [rarer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expectedly,unexpectedly&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) than the word *unexpectedly*. Maybe that's to be expected?

Comment: But if bad weather was expected, but the degree of inclemency was unexpected, then *unexpectedly inclement* would work. I have a feeling that you quote the original example, but how about "Due to the unexpectedly inclement weather conditions, even the cross-country run has been cancelled."

Comment: @AndrewLeach: You (and Fumble) and correct, I think. The wording struck me as odd, perhaps because only half a sentence was provided by the O.P. I think I might need to edit my answer some; thanks for your comment!